# Request Python Jupyter Notebook to wait for input and avoid time out

Tags: python, loops, jupyter-notebook

I have Jupyter Notebook at work which has been set to time out by admin if there is no activities detected within the notebook after a certain time. If it times out, I need to restart the kernel and lose all objects or current work. Imagine that means you go for lunch, come back and have to execute all the time-consuming script again to re-calculate the objects.

I noticed that if some code is running, the session is kept alive. I am thinking of keeping an infinite loop that keeps pinging or output something, and can be interrupted by some input when I come back.

How can I ask Jupyter Notebook to wait and listen for input in this case ?

Comment: If you have an object that is time consuming to calculate, then why not calc it once and [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) it, then re-use the pickled object and continue on from that state? That way you're not using up whatever processes your admin is trying to free up on useless non-work. Barring that, perhaps your admin would extend the idle timer, or allow a time frame for the kernel not to time out.

Comment: Spark Dataframe cannot be pickled. And keep pickling un-pickling is a hassle. Every time you are away from your post you'll have to pickle a different set of objects, restart kernel and unpickle them.

Comment: That's detail that wasn't included in your question. In that case, my second point still stands, have you asked the administrator to extend the timeout period rather than getting into an arms race over processor cycles? They may have a good reason to cut off idle sessions. If that route is a non-starter, then you could define a simple function that increments a counter every 60 seconds with `time.sleep(60)` for the duration of your expected absence

Comment: I am more interested in how to interrupt an infinite loop by some signal as wanted. _for the duration of your expected absence_ don't you think it means if I estimate my absence is 1 hour and come back in 40 min, I have to wait for 20 min more for my loop to finish ? And I wish _ask the administrator_ is as easy as you suggest.

Comment: One thing that _might_ work is just to put `q=input('Ready to continue?')` in a cell. Until you enter something in the prompt, the kernel shows as busy while it waits for the input. Whether that's enough to hold the timeout, not sure.